# accessing my webmail via Heroku (dns records)

Tags: heroku, dns, webmail

I need some help with accessing my webmail.

What I want to do is to use my own domain name (which I can do by "custom domains" I suppose) and use my personal nsMail which came with my domain name.

To be able to use my domain name, my domain provider need to have the correct DNS informations. I don't know how and where to get those informations.

Also, I want to access my webmail. When I talked with my webmail provider (which is the same as my domain provider), they told me that I had to give some details on my webmail (DNS records) to my web hosting provider (which is heroku) so that I could access my mail.

Thank you for your help